# Magento 2 display only 5 products in wishlist

Tags: php, css, ubuntu, magento, magento2

I would like to display only 5 products in the wishlist but I cannot find where to change the code to achieve this.

I have tried lots of options but I cannot find the effective path of the block.

How can i find the wishlist  path  in Magento 2?

Comment: please add some of the code you've tried and some more details about what you want to achieve. where do you want to display this whishlist?

Comment: ah, and try to use the developer tool to display block paths to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite `vendor/magento/module_wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/list.phtml` in your theme. by creating the following file: `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/list.phtml`

At the end of your foreach you can break it by adding:

```
if($iterator==5) break;
```

Comment: Next time, you can also ask your questions in:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/